# I want to call a jquery variable in php syntax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I want to call a jQuery variable in PHP syntax.

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
cardID = $(this).attr('id');
$('#card-front-img').html('<img src="{{ asset("public/nfc-assets/cards-imgs/'+cardID+'/front-preview.png") }}">');
```

at `+cardID+` I want to pass card id dynamically. But by this code, It print `+cardID+` as a string.

Comment: what is the datatype of javaScript variable you are passing?

Comment: for example: cardID = 'aquaBlue';

Comment: in your example, cardID is a string, so there is nothing wrong here

Comment: I dont understand what php have to do with this question? i only see jquery being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't pass js-variable into blade syntax since you can't execute browser code in a php code. You have to change approach. Manipulate with img path right in the js code.

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
    var cardID = $(this).attr('id');
    var imgPath = '{{ asset("public/nfc-assets/cards-imgs/cardID/front-preview.png") }}';
    $('#card-front-img').html('<img src="' + imgPath.replace('cardID', cardID) + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JavaScript variable directly.

However you can create asset url with a placeholder, which can be replaced later.

```
$('.card').on('click', function () {
    //Create a URL with placeholder
    var str = '{{ asset("public/nfc-assets/cards-imgs/__REPLACE_WITH_CARD_ID__/front-preview.png") }}';

    //Replace placeholder with card id
    str = str.replace('__REPLACE_WITH_CARD_ID__', $(this).attr('id'));

    //Use variable
    $('#card-front-img').html('<img src="' + str + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem,

Your problem is not php, but the way you append the variable,

Remove your blade syntax since it is not recognize inside jquery and also rewrite your quotes,

Replace it with this

```
$('#card-front-img').html("<img src='/public/nfc-assets/cards-imgs/"+cardID+"/front-preview.png'>");
```